# Academia — Top User Swag!

Tags: discussion

I come bringing good news! If your name is on the first two pages of:

https://academia.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

...you'll be getting an e-mail from me soon to send you a little care package, as a token of our appreciation for being awesome and making this site a success! Inside the little blue box of wonders we're gonna send you, you'll find:

A T-SHIRT!

[image: T-SHIRTS!!!!!!!]

STICKERS!

[image: STICKERS!!!!!!!!]

I should be in touch early next week with. Be sure to fill out the form as soon as you're able to do so — you'll have two weeks to do it, after which this stuff will be shipped your way! I could try to offer a precise prediction for when these will arrive at your doorstep, but we all know what 6 to 8 weeks means around these parts.

If you're not on the list, don't worry too much about it — we've got some extra swag in our swag vaults we can send to you for events and such.

Thanks to all of you for making this site great!

Comment: Does this mean I have to find out my t-shirt size, moreover in some American system? I really need to make [Clothes.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93374/clothes?referrer=x5gk8vOgaR_YfSmPBi8DoA2) a thing to help me handle such challenges.

Comment: I hope you are also shipping to Switzerland, because I am unreasonably looking forward to this :)

Comment: I am getting a t-shirt. Cool!!!

Comment: I second @Wrzlprmft; any chance of getting the t-shirt sizing as given by the manufacturer?

Comment: I've included a size chart for guidance in the form.

Comment: just received the email. very excited. Thanks -:)

Comment: @xLeitix We're shipping everywhere ;)

Comment: This is very nice, thanks!

Comment: Hurray! Way to go for the Christmas season! Thanks a bundle!

Comment: I love the current top "related" entry: [What to do about belligerent users?](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/q/39/4140)

Comment: All that procrastination has finally paid off! Thanks a bunch :D

Comment: Cool stuff! But no girls t-shirts? Also, what will you do with our personal data afterwards?

Comment: “for having helped this site grow healthily 'till it reached graduation.” – Actually, when the site graduated, I had 172 reputation.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.

Comment: @JonEricson Did you get your Academia swag??

Comment: @AustinHenley: That’s not how you get that hat.

Comment: A minor complaint about the t-shirt design: the text reads only "academia", not "academia.stackexchange.com"; so it could be mistaken for a shirt recommending academia.edu, a [quite](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16050/why-does-academia-edu-reserve-the-right-to-sell-modify-and-exploit-my-papers) [controversial](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/44632/is-academia-edu-useful) "academic social network". This association is a bit unfortunate. Please take this only as a suggestion for the future; I am not complaining about this welcome present; I thank you warmly for it.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: I'm not sure most people will connect the shirt with _any_ website at all unless they recognize the logo. The first time I wore my Stack Exchange shirt in public, someone asked if it had something to do with Wall Street. :-) Hopefully people seeing you in your shirt will either already be familiar with this site or just assume you are really excited about higher education.

Comment: @JonEricson I work in a university in Italy; the English word "academia" is not commonplace there, and I am afraid that most of my colleagues will associate it to the spam mail they got from academia.edu as their first thought. Anyway, I realize that it is probably too late to suggest a change of design. I will test if my prediction is accurate by wearing the t-shirt and seeing the reaction of my colleagues. :)

Comment: The swag has been shipped!

Comment: The swag has been received!

Comment: The swag just arrived here in Italy, too, thanks! Unfortunately, my fears have been confirmed in the very minute when I unpacked the t-shirt. A colleague entered my room exactly at that time, and she asked me what the t-shirt was. "It's from a website, do you know it?" "Uh, isn't it something like Researchgate?" :/

Comment: Thank you very much!